# std::is_assignable and std::pair<const T, U>

Tags: c++, c++11

As expected, the following code [does not compile](https://godbolt.org/g/4wKS0F).

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
int main()
{
    using T = std::pair<const int, int>;
    const auto ok = std::is_assignable<T, T>::value; // true
    T x;
    T y;
    x = y; // compiler error
}
```

But the value of `ok` [is true](http://cpp.sh/5lmnd) with the following three compilers.

- g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
- clang version 3.8.0-2ubuntu4 (tags/RELEASE_380/final)
- MSVC++ 2017 15.2 26430.6

Why is this?

Comment: Can you try to compile it with a system that gives you the actual error messages, and show them to us?

Comment: how can `ok` have a value if it does not compile?

Comment: How did you deduce it's true exactly? A static assertion on OK fails. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aba0debbfc609c11

Comment: `std::cout << std::boolalpha << ok << '\n';` outputs `false` with Clang 5.0.

Comment: Also, if the code you show doesn't compile, how do you know that `ok` is `true`? Because [I can't replicate it](http://ideone.com/tlPkfl).

Comment: `ok` is true for gcc < 6.3.

Comment: Just added a link to my question showing ok is true. It's the same in MSVC++ 2015.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/g/cMfcBP As Holt said, it is true for gcc <6.3 so it looks like a bug

Comment: A bug in three different compilers, awesome. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `is_assignable` asks the question "is there an assignment operator signature that accepts these arguments", not "will that assignment operator actually compile" (in standardese, it only considers the *immediate context* of the assignment expression):

   ```
   template<class T>
   struct foo {
       T t {};
       foo& operator=(const foo& r) { t = r.t; };
   };
   static_assert(std::is_copy_assignable<foo<const int>>::value, ""); // OK

   void bar() {
       foo<const int> f1, f2;
       f1 = f2; // explodes
   }
   ```
2. `pair`'s assignment operators can't be defaulted, because it needs to do something special when the pair contains a reference. That means that additional precautions need to be taken to ensure that `is_assignable` doesn't lie (e.g., making sure that the copy assignment operator is deleted if a member type is not copy assignable). The standard has not mandated such precautions until [very recently](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/lwg-issues/2729).
3. `is_assignable<T, T>` asks whether a `T` rvalue can be assigned to a `T` *rvalue*. This is an odd question to ask.